# In wxPython Grid, creating event handler for Cell Selection disables moving the GridCursor

Tags: python, events, grid, wxpython, wxwidgets

In the program I'm writing, the user needs to be able to select a cell in the grid and edit its value. The program also shows what the value of the currently selected value is in hexadecimal (so `(0,0)` is `0x00`, `(1,3)` is `0x19`, etc.) I originally had this display be updated through a binding to the `wx.grd.EVT_GRID_SELECT_CELL` event. However, upon doing this, the GridCursor would no longer move, it would stay on (0,0). So, I added a `SetGridCursor` statement to the handler to have it move the cursor when the handler was called. However, this generated an infinite loop, as apparently `SetGridCursor` generates an `EVT_GRID_SELECT_CELL` command when called.

My question is, how do I have code that executes when a new cell is selected while still maintaining the old cell selection functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding event.Skip() at the end of my custom handler passes the event to the default handler.